# How to set a spinner into the middle of the screen with CSS?

Tags: html, css

i need some CSS help, i have a spinner for the loading page, centered totally, it is centered vertically, but now how can i center that spinner for all possible screen widths?

This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  ...

  <body>

    <div class="loading">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>

    ...

  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my stylesheet:

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}
.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  border-top: .8em solid rgba(218, 219, 223, 1);
  border-right: .8em solid rgba(218, 219, 223, 1);
  border-bottom: .8em solid rgba(218, 219, 223, 1);
  border-left: .8em solid rgba(58, 166, 165, 1);
  -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
  animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
}
.loader,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4.05em;
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since the element has a fixed width of `8em`, you could add `left: 50%` and then displace half of the element's width using `margin-left: -4px`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2nm800/)

```
.loader {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4em;
}
```

If the dimensions of the element aren't fixed and known in advance, [see my other answer for alternative options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564).

Comment: The spinner is not spinning.

Comment: @Nano - When the OP originally posted this question, they didn't post all of the code, therefore it wasn't spinning in the first place. They were just asking this question regarding a centering issue. I updated my answer to include a rotating/spinning animation. Hopefully it helps you!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, buddy :)

Comment: Can we add Loading txt as well?

Comment: The div will also need to be subject to `position: absolute;`